# How can I use knockout to achieve <object ... > <param name="someName" value="$root.someFunc" /> </object> binding

Tags: knockout.js

I am using a third party video player to show videos.  These videos should be played based on user selection and for that I should be able to pass video name to `<object... param... videoPlaer... >`

I need to bind it with knockout.

This simple javascript works (without knockout):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var BCLS = (function () {
    return {
        onMovieStartFunc: function (evt) {
            videoPlayer.loadVideo("some hard coded id");
            //I want to be able to change this id dynamically
        }
    }
}());
</script>
<object id="myObjectId">
    <param name="&#64;videoPlayer" value="videoPlayerValue"/>
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="BCLS.onMovieStartFunc" />
</object>
```

This does not work: How can I bind those properties with knockout?

JavaScript:

```
    <input type="button" data-bind='click: onMovieStartFunc' value="Start Video" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

HTML:

```
<!-- ko with: $data -->
    <object id="myObjectId">
        <param name="&#64;videoPlayer" value="videoPlayerValue"/>
        <param name="templateLoadHandler" value="onMovieStartFunc" />
    </object>

    <input type="button" data-bind='click: onMovieStartFunc' value="Start Video" />
<!-- /ko -->
```

I created a jsFiddle to make sure I am explaining correctly

http://jsfiddle.net/acharyakrishna/ppZx5/2/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *bind* to those parameters.

Since you're binding to the `value` attribute, you can use the [`value`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) binding.

```
<object id="myObjectId">
    <param name="&#64;videoPlayer" data-bind="value: videoPlayerValue"/>
    <param name="templateLoadHandler" data-bind="value: onMovieStartFunc" />
</object>

<input type="button" data-bind='click: onMovieStartFunc' value="Start Video" />
```

If you needed to bind to other attributes besides `value`, you can use the [`attr`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding to handle them.

p.s., The `<!-- ko with: $data -->` is redundant and not needed. No need to complicate things further.

Comment: I've never worked with the `object` element before, but I'm not sure what is supposed to go in the `templateLoadHandler` parameter... that may need to be adjusted.

Comment: Uhhhaa! data-bind="value: $root.videoPlayerValue" worked for me, I can bind the value now.  Thanks much for the direction.

Comment: templateLoadHandler is an event handler that this third party video company is using in order to start the movie when the page is loaded, so user doesn't have to click "Start Video", imagine YouTube where you don't have to click "Play now", it automatically starts ads and then movie.  Pointing the event handler just like above data-binding fixed it too.
This is what I did: <param name="templateLoadHandler" data-bind="value: onMovieStartFunc" />
And, the <object...> object successfully invoked the event handler and called knockout viewmodel's function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your issue is, but from the comment in the fiddle about starting the movie on page load - you have to do that yourself. Knockout doesn't know to magically call a function on your vm. Another thing I would do is make sure that you're calling `applyBindings` after document.ready has fired.

if you have jQuery available..

```
$(function() {
  vm = new ObjectsViewModel();
  ko.applyBindings(vm);
  vm.onMovieStartFunc()
});
```

Comment: That event handler already gets executed by some mumbo jumbo (here not trying to offend anyone, it's just that I don't understand how that happens, it's a third party company's component), I just needed the event handler to invoke a method that is in the viewmodel instead of outside the viewmodel.  By binding it in below way, it fixed the issue: <param name="templateLoadHandler" data-bind="value: onMovieStartFunc" />   Thanks for your input.